# How to toggle WP Customizer Panel and Section with JavaScript API?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I am using code below to toggle customizer controls, but not sure how to toggle Panel/Sections in the same way? Any one can help me please.

```
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() { // Ready?
    var customize = this; // Customize object alias.
    customize( 'display_blogname', function( value ) {

        // ...previous codes...

        var colorControls = [
            'header_textcolor',
            'header_textcolor_hover'
        ];

        $.each( colorControls, function( index, id ) {
            customize.control( id, function( control ) {
                /**
                 * Toggling function
                 */
                var toggle = function( to ) {
                    control.toggle( to );
                };

                // 1. On loading.
                toggle( value.get() );

                // 2. On value change.
                value.bind( toggle );
            } );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using jQuery `toggle`. This is directly manipulating the visibility of DOM elements. Instead, you should be using the `active` state for the control, section, or panel. You can hide a control via `control.active.set(false)`. You can do the same for a `panel` or `section`. See some more examples in my post [Dependently-Contextual Customizer Controls](https://make.xwp.co/2016/07/24/dependently-contextual-customizer-controls/). See also my answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/286294/8521

To do the same with a panel or section, you'd do:

```
wp.customize.panel( 'idOfPanel', function( panel ) {
    panel.active.set( false ); // Hide it.
    // ...
} );

wp.customize.section( 'idOfSection', function( section ) {
    section.active.set( true ); // Show it.
    // ...
} );
```

In the “...” you'd probably want to also override the `validate` method on the `active` state to force to have a certain value so that when the Customizer preview refreshes, the `active_callback` doesn't override what you set in JS.