# How do I add a customizer control dynamically?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have the ol' dandy customizer controls, this is what I use to create a text field for my header**s**:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'ju_header_settings', array(
                                                            'title'     => __('Header Settings', '_s'),
                                                            'priority'  => 31
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_custom_text_top', array(
                                                            'default'   => 'talking about',
                                                            'transport' => 'refresh'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
                                    'header_text_1', 
                                    array(
                                        'label'     => __( 'Header Text #1', '_s'),
                                        'section'   => 'ju_header_settings',
                                        'settings'  => 'header_custom_text_top',
                                        'type'      => 'text',
                                    )
) );
```

Now, it just so happens that **now I have multiple headers. Each with a different layout and component added to it.**

This means the users can choose, from another control, which header they'd like to use:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_style', array(
                                                'default'   => 'style-1',
                                                'transport' => 'refresh'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize,
                                    'header_selector', 
                                    array(
                                        'label'     => __( 'Select the Header You Want', '_s'),
                                        'section'   => 'ju_header_settings',
                                        'settings'  => 'header_style',
                                        'type'      => 'radio',
                                        'choices'   => array(
                                                        'style-1'   => 'Style One Header',
                                                        'style-2'   => 'Style Two Header',
                                        )
                                    )
) );
```

My "pick the header" setting is something that the users should see first, before they see anything else. Then once they select the main style, based on what header they picked, a certain set of controls (tied to that specific header and only that) should appear dynamically. Keep in mind, this should all happen within the same Customizer section.

Here's a schema of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Schema]

I can't even begin to work on this due to no resources on the web that could point me in the right direction. What I could do is insert a custom class for each control and with JS, hide the certain controls that I don't need, but that feels extremely messy. Especially with keeping in mind garbage collection, where certain things need to be accounted for:

1. What if the user wants another new style? Do I cache the settings
   for that style they now no longer use for future usage?
2. The controls themselves, do I load them all together or do I load
       them dynamically as the user picks from the dropdown?

How could I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really used Customizer, but what you need is called „conditional display” (at least this is the term used in ACF & co).

That being said, I found this article that may help you:

https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/3783/conditional-displaying-and-hiding-of-customizer-controls-via-javascript/

Also, this SE topic:

[Is it possible to conditionally displaying and hiding of customizer controls for each device preview?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286268/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-displaying-and-hiding-of-customizer-controls-for/286294)